# Read two lines at a time from a txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools, readline, readlines

The 1st piece of code shown below reads one line from a txt file

It reads one line at a time but what I'd like to achive is making it read two lines at once.

I tried to call the function twice, but all what it does is it reads the same line and print it twice.

I tried using the itertools and islice function but it doesn't seem to be working, I'm missing something.

Sorry, it's the result of 8 days experience with Python .

How can I make it read N lines at once?

```
file = open('textfile.txt', 'r')
filelines = file.readlines()
file.close()

for line in filelines:
    if line != '\n':
        api.update_status(line)
...
```

An attempt to resolve the problem using islice().

```
from itertools import islice

with open('file.txt') as file:

  while True:

    next_n_lines = islice(file, 2)

    if not next_n_lines:

        break
```

Comment: Call `readline()` to get the first line, and call it again to get the second line.

Comment: Please add your attempt to your question.

Comment: Please provide an example of your code, show us how you read one line and someone should be able to tell you how to read the second as well

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I've edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can iterate over the file using enumerate to get line numbers, and simply store even number lines in a temp variable, and move on to the next odd number line. On odd number lines you can then have access to the previous line as well as the current line.

```
with open('somefile.txt', 'r') as f:
    lastline = ''
    for line_no, line in enumerate(f):
        if line_no % 2 == 0: #even number lines (0, 2, 4 ...) go to `lastline`
            lastline = line
            continue #jump back to the loop for the next line
        print("here's two lines for ya")
        print(lastline)
        print(line)
```

Comment: Thank you so much brother Aaron, it worked like charm, I've trying and searching for a way for almost 3 hours, Thank yooou

Comment: @MrStrange_M.S this is just one option. it might be a good learning experience to explore some of the other options mentioned in the comments. For example if you're simply iterating over `f`, you can call `next(f)` in the body of the for loop to get the next value before going back to the top of the loop. Of note, that call may raise a `StopIteration` exception, which you would have to catch with a `try: except:` block.

Comment: Yeah, I will for sure, I'm really sorry I can't upvote your answer because I still don't have 15 reputations to upvote answers

Comment: yeah bro I added a try: except: block, your answer and clarifications were helpful, thank you so much. bro can you please check out the question and vote for it to be reopened if you find it goes inline with the community policies. 3 people voted for it to be closed, I edited it to make it clear, because of that, I can't post another question